# vim: search replace over all writable buffers

Tags: vim, replace

so

```
1GvG:s/..../g
```

can replace over an entire buffer

However, suppose I have multiple vim buffers loaded, and I want to do a :s over all the buffers that are writable; is there a way to do this in vim?

Comment: Btw you can just do `%s` for the entire buffer.

Comment: Thank you for asking this! It's been a nagging question for me (but not too nagging or I'd have asked it here too).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since I can't leave comments, I'll be repeating what Brian said and adding in my 2 cents.

I believe the command you're looking for is:

```
:bufdo :%s/..../g | :w
```

Note: This will write each file after the changes are made, so make sure you're ready for this.

If autowrite is on, you should be able to remove the "| :w" at the end of the command.

Comment: Well, at least in my vim (7.2, Ubuntu) it's enough to leave the `| :w` out of the picture if you don't want to write on change.

Comment: There's a page on the vim wiki dedicated to this http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace_in_multiple_buffers with more options regarding the trailing `| :w`

Comment: @AdrianoVaroliPiazza It works out of the box without the `| :w` on `vim` but is required for `vi`.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [`bufdo`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:bufdo). There's also `windo` and `tabdo`. Keep in mind that per default Vim doesn't autowrite so for search/replace commands across buffer you need to turn on autowrite.

Answer (score 0):

[Greplace](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1813) has a feature that supports this.  There's also a [pathogen ready version](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Greplace.vim) on github.