# How do I do a substitution on all open buffers?

Tags: vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [vim: search replace over all writable buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445688/vim-search-replace-over-all-writable-buffers)

I can use `:%s/foo/blah/g` to replace all occurrences of "foo" with "blah" in the current buffer. And how can I do it on *all* open buffers at once?

Comment: @sidyll: thanks, I should have used "search and replace" instead of "substitution" in my search terms :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use bufdo to operate on all open buffers.

`:help bufdo`

#### Example:

`:bufdo %s/main/mains/`

Will run the search and replace on all open buffers.